# Reference request: Every self-diffeomorphism of $S^3$ is isotopic to the identity

Tags: reference-request, spheres, low-dimensional-topology

I am searching for a reference with a proof of the statement: Every orientation preserving self-diffeomorphism of $S^3$ is isotopic to the identity. I searched in many books aswell as online, but did not find anything other than the statement in the PL category. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please do not use [tag:reference-request] as the only tag for a question

Comment: The inclusion of SO(4) into the diffeomorphism group of S^3 is a homotopy equivalence, according to a theorem of Hatcher (it's called the Smale conjecture, iirc) That does what you want, no?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Is the argument that for any two self-diffeomorphism, we can via homotopy map them into $SO(4)$, in which we choose a path between them which gives the desired isotopy?

Comment: Yup. Notice that only uses the fact that SO(4) is path connected, Hatcher's theorem.proves much much more (probably what you need was know before)

Comment: It's due to Cerf, 1968, LNM, vol. 53.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you very much!